# Is the on-topic help page supposed to be exhaustive?

Tags: discussion

Is the [on-topic help page](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) supposed to be exhaustive? By exhaustive, I mean it contains all admissible topics, and any topic not listed there is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

No, that would be an ever-changing target.  The on-topic help page is supposed to describe the general scope, but there will always be edge cases.  And especially during the beta stage, a site's scope can be in some amount of flux.

All that said, this site's on-topic page would benefit from an "and not about..." section -- if your question is about A, B, C, or D, *and not about* E, F, or G, then you can ask it here.  That way the page provides both positive and negative "signposts". Some examples of this style:

- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)
- [Role-Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)